# Disable path output message in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I run a .java file in Intellij, I see the following message:

```
C:\Users\Username\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.1.....

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there a way to disable this message?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment.

You can [vote for the corresponding request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259009/Option-to-hide-run-command-and-exit-code-from-the-output) in YouTrack.